# Tcl : why the variable does not get increment?

Tags: tcl

What I would like to ask you is, why the following snippet does *not* increment the variable `$times` ?

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh 

set logging { 
LC/0/1/CPU0:Jan 27 08:24:17.014 CET: ifmgr[175]: %PKT_INFRA-LINK-3-UPDOWN : Interface GigabitEthernet0/1/0/33, changed state to Down 
LC/0/1/CPU0:Jan 27 08:24:17.014 CET: ifmgr[175]: %PKT_INFRA-LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN : Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet0/1/0/33, changed state to Down 
}
set times 0
set records [ split $logging "\n" ] 
foreach rec $records { 
    puts $rec
    incr $times 1
    puts $times       ;# puts [ incr $times 1 ]
}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be

```
incr times 1
```

or simply

```
incr times
```

Answer (score 5):

In Tcl, the name of the variable is `times`; `$times` means “read `times` now and use the value read from it”. When you're wanting to increment a variable, you need to tell the increment command the name of the variable to adjust, i.e., you need to pass `times` and not the contents of the `times` variable (which is what `$times` does, which works out to passing `0` in; a legal variable name but probably not what you wanted; putting variable names in variables is not normally recommended because it tends to make programmers' heads ache).

Thus, instead of `incr $times 1` you want:

```
incr times
```

(The `1` is optional; it's the default amount to increment by.)

Comment: Reading this bit from the tutorial also recommended http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl2.html (Reading the whole tutorial is recommended as well.)